# Don't load part of html until button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, hide

I'm creating a one page sited, with just one container of info. The content of the container will switch when a user clicks specific buttons on the left. However, At this very moment the site will load each of the content parts. One of those contains my portfolio, which (will be) a big image collection, which stops the site from loading fast.

Therefor I don't want to make the content of a specific  load until the button to show the content of that div is clicked.

For a quick example of what I'm trying to achieve:
Visit http://iscs.nl/testpage_changecontent.html

The content of the div that shouldn't be loaded at start is #page_portfolio
Which will be shown by clicking on a button #pagebutton_portfolio
Note: These ID's aren't used on the testpage, of the above link.

Thanks guys, lookin' forward to the code.

Comment: search for jquery .load() method which is just an ajax shorthand method. Here is the DOC: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: What you are looking for is load the content uppon request which is commonly done via AJAX. references : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Why is this off-topic? It's about websites, pages and HTML and such as DOM-loading, by use of Javascript and/or PHP. So why is this off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming the portfolio content was in `portfolio.html`:

```
$('#tabcontent2').click(function(e){
  $('#content_1').hide();
  $("#content_2").show()
    // grab portoflio.html and place its contents within #content_2
    .load('portfolio.html');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

You may even want to use the `data-*` attributes so you don't reload the page (fetch once):

```
$('#tabcontent1').click(function(e){
  $('#content_2').hide();
  $('#content_1').show();
  e.preventDefault();
});
$('#tabcontent2').click(function(e){
  $('#content_1').hide();

  var $content2 = $("#content_2").show();

  // check if it's been loaded before
  if (!($('#content_2').data('loaded') || false)){
    // grab portoflio.html and place its contents within #content_2
    $content2.load('portfolio.html', function(){
      // set the flag to say we've already loaded this content
      $content2.data('loaded',true);
    });
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Wow, that looks great mate. Thanks!

Haven't tested, but it looks just what I want.

The idea of external content (individual .html files for each content) also stops the 'one-page' from cluttered. 

Seems great. Thanks! 
Once i've tested it (-and works), you'll sure get thumbs up!

Comment: What is the purpose of `|| false` in your check? Why not: `if (!$('#content_2').data('loaded'))` ?

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer: `.load` can also target specific elements, so to keep things universal i would create your site using a global template with each page only specifying that page's content, then use AJAX and supplement the navigation (like [this](https://gist.github.com/bchristie/6699988)).

Comment: @A.Wolff: To make it more clear that we're looking for a true value. `||false` means that if `.data('loaded')` returns `undefined` we want it to result in a `false`. Granted, `undefined` is falsy, it just makes it more clear (IMHO).

Comment: @A.Wolff: yes, I actually fixed that when you made the comment. ;-)

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see your edit

Comment: @A.Wolff: Just updated that [gist](https://gist.github.com/bchristie/6699988) with a working version. Create each one of those files in a folder on your desktop and you can see how it works. Also added comments to explain each portion. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax for loading the content. You will need a php file, but it only gets executed when the js event is fired.

Comment: You don't _need_ a php file, just content on the server that an AJAX call can retrieve (and render). This could very well be `othercontent.html`

Comment: That's true. .php ext is somehow glued to my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple decision specially for you.

1. Put two files with content (without layout) to your server. For example, content1.html and content2.html
2. replace your existing JS code with this one:

   ```
   function replace(content) {
       $('#content').html(content);
       $('#content').show();
   }

   $('#tabbutton1').click(function() {
       $.get("content1.html", replace(content));
       $('#content').hide();
   });

   $('#tabbutton2').click(function() {
       $.get("content2.html", replace(content));
       $('#content').hide();
   });
   ```
3. finally, replace your divs with ids "content_1" and "content_2" to single div with id="content":

   ```
   <div id="content">The text displayed until the user clicks any link</div>
   ```

Best regards.